# Unable to create Azure Function keys, using terraform azapi

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure, azapi

I am trying to create the function keys using terraform

```
resource "azapi_resource" "symbolicname" {
  type = "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/keys@2022-09-01"
  name = "Random"
  parent_id = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/fa-test-fucntions/functions/testcreatkey"
  body = jsonencode({
    value = "hhundredslkkjjsiiskkk"
  })
}
```

but getting below error,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ RESPONSE 400: 400 Bad Request
│ ERROR CODE UNAVAILABLE
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ {
│   "Code": "BadRequest",
│   "Message": "Properties object is not present in the request body.",
│   "Target": null,
│   "Details": [
│     {
│       "Message": "Properties object is not present in the request body."
│     },
│     {
│       "Code": "BadRequest"
│     },
│     {
│       "ErrorEntity": {
│         "ExtendedCode": "51006",
│         "MessageTemplate": "{0} object is not present in the request body.",
│         "Parameters": [
│           "Properties"
│         ],
│         "Code": "BadRequest",
│         "Message": "Properties object is not present in the request body."
│       }
│     }
│   ],
│   "Innererror": null
│ }
```

Basically I wanted to save  fucntion keys using terraform into KV secret, So I thought of trying  to create the keys and then storing the value in KV

Any help, appreciated

Comment: There is built-in functionality to use Azure Key Vault as the backing store for the function keys.  I would recommend [trying this mechanism](https://dev.to/massimobonanni/azure-functions-tips-how-to-store-the-functions-app-keys-into-keyvault-4nij) instead of trying to do it with Terraform.

Comment: @Adam the above link did not work properly but this one did
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-store-function-app-s-function-keys-in-a-key-vault/ba-p/2639181
but thanks for suggestion

Comment: Sorry, the link still works for me.  Not sure what the problem is, but I'm glad the suggestion helped!